# Vimeo App Creation - No Authentication Options?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to use a plugin for my CMS, which is apparently still dependant on the oAuth 1.0 authentication method. In my account, I have no such option for choosing oAuth vs. oAuth2, but apparently some people do? See that attached screenshot I got from support. These options do not appear in my control panel. Can someone explain why this is?

Screenshot of the authentication options I'm looking for but are missing: http://par.sc/1dTIP/4WEtcpCh

Answer (score 0):

oAuth 1.0 is part of the Advanced API. The Advanced API is no longer supported, in favor of the current [API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api).

Comment: My point was that some users still enjoy the option of using the Advanced API. I reached out to Vimeo support and they were able to re-enable access to the Advanced API. The best and most prominent Vimeo add-ons for ExpressionEngine are all still using the old API so until these plug-ins are updated, we're a bit stuck using the old API.

Comment: The old API is still online out of a service to those users. It will be shut down in the future (Vimeo will give plenty of notice), and that option needs to be weighed by every user who requests access to the old API. If your CMS does not convert, your app might permanently break within the next year or two.